# How to get the value of multiple checkbox elements with the same name in my controller

Tags: symfony, twig

I have following code in my twig file:

```
<form method ="POST" action="{{path('deleteMessages')}}">
                {% for message in pmReceived %}
                    {% if message.isread == false  %}
                        {% if message.showincoming == true  %}
                            <div class="border">
                                <div  class="pmbox">
                                    <p class="pmsender">{{message.sender}}</p><p class="pmdate">{{message.date|date('d-m-Y H:i:s') }}</p><p class="pmsubject">{{message.subject}}</p><input type="checkbox" name="deletePm" value="{{message.pmid}}">
                                </div>
                                <div class="pmcontents">
                                    <p class="titleContent">Contents:</p>
                                    <p>{{message.contents}}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                {% for message in pmReceived %}
                    {% if message.isread == true %}
                        {% if message.showincoming == true  %}
                            <div class="border">
                                <div class="pmbox">
                                    <p class="pmsender">{{message.sender}}</p><p class="pmdate">{{message.date|date('d-m-Y H:i:s') }}</p><p class="pmsubject">{{message.subject}}</p><input type="checkbox" name="deletePm" value="{{message.pmid}}">
                                </div>
                                <div class="pmcontents">
                                    <p class="titleContent">Contents:</p>
                                    <p>{{message.contents}}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                <button class="deleteButton" type="submit">Delete selected messages</button>
            </form>
```

This is my controller code:

```
public function deleteMessagesAction(Request $request) {
    if (false === $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
        throw $this->createAccessDeniedException('Unable to access this page!');
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $pm = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('LoginLoginBundle:Privatemessage')
            ->findBypmid($request->get('sentValue'));
    $deleteMessages = $request->get('deletePm');
    var_dump($deleteMessages);

    $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    $pmReceived = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('LoginLoginBundle:Privatemessage')
            ->findByReceiver($user->getUsername());

    $pmSent = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('LoginLoginBundle:Privatemessage')
            ->findBySender($user->getUsername());

    return $this->render('LoginLoginBundle:Default:pmPage.html.twig', array('pmReceived' => $pmReceived, 'pmSent' => $pmSent, 'toDelete'=>$deleteMessages));

}
```

Now I want to get the value of all the 'ticked' checkboxes, I supposed $deleteMessages would be an array of values, but it only holds the last checkbox that is ticked.

How can I get an array of all the values in my controller?

Comment: Change the name from `deletePm` to `deletePm[]`. This will create an array of all checked checkboxes  in the post rather than the last checked one.

Comment: Do you mean change $deleteMessages to $deleteMessages[]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

U need to alter the name of your inputs.
This way u will receive an array of checked checkboxes instead of only the last checked one:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="deletePm[]" value="{{message.pmid}}">
```

This will result in an array equal to :

```
   [
        0  => 1,
        1  => 10,
        2  => ...,
   ]
```

U then can just loop this array to delete accordingly :

```
$deleteMessages = $request->get('deletePm');
foreach($deleteMessages  as $deleteMessageId) {
    //Do something with the ID
}
```